# function takePath incorrect on input

Tags: javascript

```
function takePath(jstring, move) {
    var string = JSON.parse(jstring);
    var crystal = 0;
    var grid = string['grid'];
    var start = string['start'];
    var x = start[0];
    var y = start[1];
    for (var i of move) {
        start = movePlayer(string, move[i]);
        if (grid[y][x] === 0 || grid[y][x] === 2) {
            if (grid[y][x] == 2) {
                crystal += 1;
                grid[y][x] = 0;
            }
        }
        var object = {
            "location": start, 
            "crystals": crystal
        };
        return object;
    }
}

function movePlayer(string, move){
    var start = string['start'];
    var grid = string['grid'];
    var x = start[0];
    var y = start[1];
    var len = grid.length;
    var xaxis = 0;
    var yaxis = 0;
    if (move === 'w'){
        y = start[1] - 1;
        yaxis = yaxis - 1;
        if (y > len - 1){
            return start;
        }
        if (y < 0){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 1){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 3){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 7){
            return start;
        }
        else;
        return [x,y];
    }
    if (move === 'a'){
        x = start[0] - 1;
        xaxis = xaxis - 1;
        if (x > len - 1){
            return start;
        }
        if (x < 0){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 1){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 3){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 7){
            return start;
        }
        else;
        return [x,y];
    }
    if (move === 's'){
        y = start[1] + 1;
        yaxis = yaxis + 1;
        if (y > len - 1){
            return start;
        }
        if (y < 0){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 1){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 3){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 7){
            return start;
        }
        else;
        return [x,y];
    }
    if (move === 'd'){
        x = start[0] + 1;
        xaxis = xaxis + 1;
        if (x > len - 1){
            return start;
        }
        if (x < 0){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 1){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 3){
            return start;
        }
        if (grid[y][x] == 7){
            return start;
        }
        else;
        return [x,y];
    }
    return start;
}
```

Part 3: Let's now expand the takePath function to track the number of crystals collected by the player. Start with your solution to part 2 and expand it for this part. Write a function named "takePath" that takes as parameters a JSON string representing a level in the format above and an array of strings representing the moves of the player in the order they are taken where each move is either "w", "a", "s", or "d" using the same standard as in parts 1 and 2. Return an object containing the keys "location" storing the new player location as an array in the format [x, y] and "crystals" storing the number of crystals the player collected along the path. You may assume that that there are no keys, locked doors, boots, lava tiles, or exit on the level. You may also assume that the player does not start on a crystal

returned: {'crystals': 0, 'location': [2, 1]}
expected: {'crystals': 1, 'location': [3, 1]}

Here's the input:  ['{"start": [2, 1], "grid": [[1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0, 2], [2, 2, 2, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0]]}', ['d', 'w', 's', 'a', 'd', 'd']]

The code was NOT given to us; I wrote this by myself.  I'm trying to figure out why the output is incorrect.

Comment: If the code you've shown is not part of the assignment but your solution then it would be good if you explain it to us, and also provide the sample input that produced the wrong result.

Comment: I edited accordingly, thanks.